# MySQL ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 22: Table 'gec_stage.ACTIVATION' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I am importing a dump file i received into an empty database I created on Mysql. When I try to import, it gives me the below error. I really need help. Thanks

MySQL ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 22: Table 'gec_stage.ACTIVATION'  doesn't exist

Comment: I'm not an expert in SQL but as I know, you should get export with schema or have the schema (mean tables) before you import your data.

Comment: Does the dump file contain `CREATE TABLE` commands?

Comment: The Error message is very simple to understand. So without seeing the dump file all we can really do is sympathise.

Comment: Should I cat the dump file to see the CREATE TABLE  commands?

Comment: That would be a good start or open it with a editor

Comment: then look for a CREATE TABLE commands? what if there is not CREATE TABLE command

Comment: Then you will need to redo the Backup on the other PC and this time check the options so that you get the CREATE TABLE Statements

Comment: this is what I see at the end of the dumpfile.  LOCK TABLES `ACTIVATION` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ACTIVATION` DISABLE KEYS */;

Comment: I have solve the issue, I believe it was the dumpfile. I got a new dump and it works